# angular firestore: Property 'find' does not exist on type 'number'

Tags: javascript, angular, google-cloud-firestore

```
private readonly firestore = inject(Firestore);

const eventsRef = collection(this.firestore, 'events');
const usersRef = collection(this.firestore, 'users');

return collectionData(eventsRef, { idField: 'id' })
  .pipe(
    switchMap(events => {
      const userIds = uniq(events.map(ev => ev.uid))
      return combineLatest(
        of(events),
        combineLatest(
          userIds.map(userId => collectionData(query(usersRef, where('uid', '==', userId)),  { idField: 'id' }).pipe(map(users => users[0]))
          )
        )
      )
    }),
    map(([events, users]) => {

      return events.map((event) => {
        return {
          event,
          user: users.find( us => us.uid === event.uid)
        }
      })
    })
  )
```

I read the whole catalog of stackoverflow solutions, but I can't find the right one.
It know events but users is unknown regardless that it was known in `.pipe(map(users => users[0]))`.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My understanding of the `map` method is that you can receive multiple parameters. The first item is going to be the value of that iteration where the second parameter is going to be the current index of iteration.

This means that `users` is going be a number, not an array as you expect. So `Number.find` is going to throw an error.

I'd suggest using `console.log` to identify the type of each iterative value.

Comment: It's an array of [events, users] so no index

Comment: Are you sure about that? The error you're getting suggests that `users` is a Number.